# Oracle Apex Create Registration Page Using default Users

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

is it possible to create a Oracle Apex Create Registration Page Using default Users which is accessible as a public page. Without creating a custom authentication.

Comment: I don't see why not, I think all the necessary APIs are available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

You can use the [APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_util.htm#BABCFBGG) procedure to create users in PL/SQL when they sign up.

Comment: APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER procedure can't called by public user, but you can call via a scheduled job. Check this solution:

https://www.traust.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Traust-APEX-Blog-Self-Registration-Instruction-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To use APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER, you need administrator privilege which is most likely new user won't have it because it is the first time they sign up.

Comment: No, you just need access to the schema that the user will be connected to